# Custom data type in Prisma

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, prisma

How to create my own data type in **Prisma**?

I want to create data type to store `TIME WITH TIMEZONE` in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `DateTime` data type and in an attribute can define to use native PostgreSQL time with timezone type.
Here's how you can define it in schema file

```
model Time {
  time DateTime @db.Timetz(6)
}
```

Here's a reference for using native database types in [docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/database-connectors/postgresql#native-type-mappings).